# Javascript and CSS animation not placing my results in the correct spot

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have Javascript and CSS animation that I am trying to show an effect that names come out of a bag in a vertical manner and then the name flips to a horizontal manner and is placed in my `.shuffled_results` div. When I try to do this on my page the name flies around in a circle and is placed in the correct spot, but I don't want the names to fly around in a circle across the screen. It looks like a bird flying around.

I created a fiddle, but the results aren't the same as what is happening in my page. I'm sure that has to do with my div being farther down the page rather than in the top corner.

https://jsfiddle.net/n2o672q3/

I have played around with a lot of this to get it to work, but nothing I do seems to work.

I have messed around a lot with this piece of code..

```
.shuffle_results {
  position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-animation:spin 3s linear;
    -moz-animation:spin 3s linear;
    animation:spin 3s linear;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this ,First place all your child content inside another div on which we will apply **overflow** attribute

```
<div class="main-bag"> <!--Making all content wrap inside main div-->
    <div class="shuffle_results" id="results">Bob</div>
    <div class="shuffle_results" id="results">George</div>  
    <div class="shuffle_results" id="results">Mary</div>
    <div class="shuffle_results" id="results">Lucy</div>
    <img id='paperBag' src="http://www.thecuriouscaterpillar.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/bag_to_white.jpg" width="200px" />
</div>
```

and then in css

```
.main-bag{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This will make sure that any child content that is positioned outside the boundary of main div gets clipped off

Comment: This didn't help. It just doesn't show the circle motion. Instead you just see the name come up and then on the other side of the screen you see it come down, then come back up again on the left side.

Comment: Because your animation is not correct , You want names to look like they appear out of bag (right ?) but your animation makes names flow out from above and land over the bag , you need to tweak your animation

Comment: @L=X Tweak the animation on what way?

Comment: just make your animation starts from bottom (of the bag) and goes to the top position (final position) this will make sure that names are appearing from bag , and you can play with opacity such that it appears more realistic ,when animation starts set opacity to zero and start incrreasing as your animation plays